# Get current ListItem with ECMAScript

Tags: javascript, custom-list, list-form

I need to calculate a value for a custom ListItem field, based on some values on the same form and also on some values from other lists. 
I should be able to do this, using ECMA Script. I started by getting the current user (I need it to query my other lists).

Now, I am trying to get my current List Item, so I can gather the fields required for the calculation.

Is there any way to do that? Am I going for the right approach.

Thank you!
Ana

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if I understood your question correctly but if you want to get the current selected item's ID then you can use below code

```
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var items = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(ctx);
```

using above ID you can get listitem. Below is the URL on how to get list items in JavaScript
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh185007(v=office.14).aspx

If you are adding any CustomAction in ECB then you can use token {ItemId}. Refer below URL to know more on tokens
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj163816.aspx

Comment: Thank you. I tried the code and the SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(ctx) returns an empty object. Maybe I didn't explain very well my scenario. Basically, when I save a new list item, I want to fill in a field, based on some other fields on the same form.

Comment: Joe's answer will be correct if you want to update any text field on form, but not sure if this will work with controls like TaxonomyField, PeopleEditor.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your reply to Vikram, i.e. updating fields before saving a new list item, you could include an additional click handler for the save controls on your page. A new item doesn't receive an ID until after it has been saved.

jQuery example:

```
$("input[value*='Save']").click(function(){
    //Update some fields here before the default save
    $("#someFieldID").val("New Value");
});
```

This should grab any save button, including the ribbon save, of a default form. If you have a custom element, just update the selector. The script inside here will execute before heading out to the built in click handler.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a way to access current page field values in SP 2010 and came across this question.

There are basically two ways I found to use fields of the current PAGE:

1. Just use the web control field value rendering as you would in any page (if you only want to display/check a value).

   ```
   console.log(' < SharePointWebControls:TextField FieldName="FormMailContact" runat="server" InputFieldLabel="FormMailContact" / > ');
   ```
2. Alternatively you can take the long road and get the value based on the current list and page id in an async call:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function () { ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getItem, "sp.js");   });

   var item;

   function getItem(){
      var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

      var web = clientContext.get_web();

      var list = web.get_lists().getById(_spPageContextInfo.pageListId);
      this.item = list.getItemById(_spPageContextInfo.pageItemId);
      clientContext.load(item);
      clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFailure));
   }

   function onSuccess(){
      if(item.get_item('FormMailContact'))
      {
           document.getElementById('agenda-form-personal-data').style.display='';
      }
   }

   function onFailure(){
      console.log('Failure!');
   }
   ```